# How I can make all my picture be on the same size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to have my pictures witch have different resolution the same size here and I tried a loot of things and I don't know why it doesn't work .
Here is the result for me https://prnt.sc/10qz5vk and when I change the state in 1,2,3 or 4 I have
I want to have [here](https://prnt.sc/10qyzk0)

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './Styles/Slide.css'
import { images } from './sliderojects';

function Slide() {

    const [currImage, setCurrImage] = useState(1);

    return (
        <div className="slide-exterior">
            <div className="slide-interior" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${images[currImage].img})` }}>
                <img src={images[currImage].img} />
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Slide

import room1 from './Media/room1.jpg';
import room2 from './Media/room2.jpg';
import room3 from './Media/room3.jpg';
import room4 from './Media/room4.jpg';

export const images = [
    {
        title: "Brasov",
        subtitle: "This is the beatiful Brasov",
        img: room1
    },
    {
        title: "Iasi",
        subtitle: "Come to check our city Iasi",
        img: room2
    },
    {
        title: "Suceava",
        subtitle: "The haert of Bucovina - Suceava",
        img: room3
    },
    {
        title: "Bucuresti",
        subtitle: "Here you can see the biggest place is Romania",
        img: room4
    },
]
```

```css
.slide-exterior{
    width: 70%;
    height: 500px;
    margin:auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.slide-interior{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Apply the objectFit property directly to the  tag

```
<img src={images[currImage].img} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover' }} />
```